# Проблема с роутерами для БД

Tags: django, база-данных

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, почему таблица `profiles` создается в не той БД? Нужно в `users_profiles`, а она создается в `users_information`. Я уверен на 100%, что проблема в routers, потому что всегда все таблицы создаются в default БД, но никак не могу понять в чем конкретно. Их код переписывал уже раз 7 - результата ноль. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'users_information',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },

    'users_profiles': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'users_profiles',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['users_registration.backend.django_registration.routers.Routers']
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_info = models.OneToOneField(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'django_registration'
        db_table = 'profiles'

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserInfo)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and not hasattr(instance, 'profile'):
        UserProfile.objects.using('users_profiles').create(user_info=instance)
```

routers.py

```
class Routers:
    def db_for_read(self, model):
        if model._meta.object_name == 'UserProfile':
            return 'users_profiles'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model):
        if model._meta.object_name == 'UserProfile':
            return 'users_profiles'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if model_name == 'UserProfile':
            return db == 'users_profiles'
        return db == 'default'
```